# Как загрузить файл на локалку?

Tags: vue.js

Как делается загрузка файла через формы

export default {
        name: "create",
        methods: {
          fileInput(event) {
              console.log(event.target.files[0])
          }
        }
    }

то есть файл я могу получить, а как его сохранить теперь у себя в локалке?
То есть их хранить во фронте нужно файлы

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем вот кусок кода из моего Angular компонента но логика остается та же:

```
  addNewImage(event) {
    const myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    const files: File[] = event.target.files;
    for(let file of files) {
      myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
      myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
        const obj = {
          name: file.name,
          base64: myReader.result
        }
        this.filesList.push(obj);
        this.filesChanged.emit(this.filesList);
      };
    }
  }
```

Где `event.target` наш file uploader input.